# Push notifications when user force quits the app

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

I have implemented onesignal in my iOS app as per the setup instructions given here (https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup).

When I install the app for the first time, I get notification from Onesignal dashboard.

When I kill the app, I still seem to get the notification.

But when I launch the app again, I stopped receiving any notification until I uninstall and install the app again.

So am I missing anything here? Do we receive push notification even if app is killed by the user?

Comment: I had older native push notification code. I removed it and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can receive push notifications on your app whether it is active, in background or killed using the NotificationServiceExtension.

The OneSignal documentation shows how to do this:
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/silent-notifications

Relevant Apple Docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension